# Switching line between 5 V and ground using a 3.3 V signal

Tags: microcontroller, level-shifting, logic-level

I am working with a PCB which looks like shown below. Switching the central line between 5 V and ground toggles the LEDs.

[image]

I had this PCB connected to a 5 V Arduino dev board where the switch line was connected to one of the GPIO pins; switching between high and low on that pin toggles the LEDs.

I have a requirement to get this working on a 3.3 V board so I need to amplify the 3.3 V GPIO pin to 5 V. I thought I could use a level shifter, I tried a TXB0104 with the 3 V signal connected to LV1 and the switch line connected to HV1 but when the pin is set to high, I only get ~3 V on the 5 V side.

[image]

Googling suggests I can achieve this using a MOSFET, but I'm very much a beginner and somewhat at a loss. What would be a simple solution to this?

Edit:

Thanks for the answers so far. I should have been clearer in my original post, the PCB in my example is an existing board which is part of a computer case IO and RGB controller. My circuit example is a smaller part of that board and the rest of the board requires 5V to operate correctly. I tried to find a schematic for the board (GYPCB-22105A-6) but couldn't find anything, I'm guessing its a proprietary board made specifically for the case. Added a picture for context.

[image]

Comment: I used a [TXB0104](https://thepihut.com/products/adafruit-txb0104-bi-directional-level-shifter?variant=27739663953&currency=GBP&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&gclid=Cj0KCQjwu-KiBhCsARIsAPztUF3diqEKvTP20QZGDVripQ08ePytH3bFk7QYrfwNFHmc51fZeRfqkp0aAmeREALw_wcB)

Comment: @Warren The reason your converter doesn't work is that it's an automatic bi-directional converter which is sometimes very nice but bad in this case because the outputs are unusually weak. This is hidden very deep in the datasheet, which annoys me. Essentially it's so weak that they don't even care to specify or mention it.

Comment: @greybeard will remember for future. I have updated the question now.

Comment: Bec aware that Leads die easily above a usually quite low reverse bias level. 5V may be enough in some cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hard way:

A single transistor can only pull that "central" node down to 0V, *or* pull up to +5V, not both. That's why a single transistor level translator can't work here. You will require a setup that can pull in *both* directions, which requires *two* transistors in a push-pull configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXoPaj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm sure you can see a potential problem here: if Q1 and Q2 are on simultaneously, this would be a direct short circuit between +5V and ground, and a lot of current will flow. Something will break unless you take great care to ensure that inputs A and B are never in a state where this condition to occur.

You could limit this so-called "shoot-through" current with resistors, further complicating the arrangement. Or you could build circuitry to control A and B independently, introducing a small delay between switching one transistor off and switching the other on. Also complicated.

Or, the easy way:

You require a digital gate that has a push-pull output stage, takes an input potential for which +3.3V is considered "high", and 0V is "low", and outputs either +5V or 0V in response. That's exactly what the 74HCT (note the "T", that's the important bit) range of logic devices do.

They have push-pull output stages, with all the problems I mentioned above already taken care of, and will translate from 3.3V logic levels to 5V. No resistors needed, no timing to take care of, no special power supply requirements.

They are available in single gate packages, such as the [74HCT1G08](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT1G08.pdf):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEXfxi.png)</sup>

You could use any gate, from any 74HCT package, such as multiple-gate devices 74HCT08, 74HCT00, 74HCT04 etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will pick up one of [these](https://uk.farnell.com/nexperia/74hct1g08gw/74hct-single-gate-smd-74hct1g08/dp/1085263) and give it go. So I fully understand, am I right in saying I would connect the pins as follows:
1: +5 V
2: +3.3/0 V from GPIO
3: Ground
4: +5/0 V switch line to the PCB
5: +5 V.
And does that mean that when pins 1 & 2 are high, pin 4 is connected to pin 5 and when either pin 1 or 2 are low, pin 4 is connected to ground?

Comment: @Warren that sounds correct.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Reduce the resistance to get the same current.  I do not know what LED you are using so I just guested on value.

Comment: This is the most practical answer. But I added my own entry just in case to explain further.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer in my description. The PCB in my example is an existing board - it is a PC case IO and RGB controller. My diagram is a small part of the board and the rest of the board requires 5v to opperate. I tried to find a schematic for the board but I came up short.

Answer (score 6):

The 74LVC series of surface mount inverters and buffers are available in single-element packages. These have a wide power supply range. The Schmitt types will allow 3.3 V to reliably switch a 5 V powered device. They have a high current drive of 24 mA, source and sink.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzAGaX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Additional information:

This is a single part solution. These devices are very small. The picture added to the OP shows this part could be glued on then air wired to connect.

Answer (score 3):

Another way that uses the 5V supply and two [small MOSFETs](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/orqxwkxkq1/ONSM-S-A0003544006-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw) (2N7002 is the SOT23 SMT version of the 2N7000)...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVE6fI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are some advantages to using the 5V supply if you have it available, in particular it may allow better control of the LED current, especially for white, blue or purple LEDs (there are other possible advantages and disadvantages in particular situations).

R2 ensures M2 is fully turned on when M1 is "off" by pulling the gate up and not depending on the voltage drop on D1 being low enough.

Answer (score -1):

The other solutions here are complex, but they missed the real question here (which you also missed as a starter but that's ok) which is: does an LED circuit really need a 5V supply that you *really* need a 3.3V to go up to 5V?

The answer is no, and thus a 3.3V Arduino board should behave just fine. But a few notes:

For LEDs you don't need specifically a 5V source per se, the important requirement for an LED is to:

1. Voltage should be above the LED minimum voltage (usually around 2V) and
2. The current should be kept at a nominal value to give the nominal light output behavior and avoid blowing out the LED, thus the need of a series resistor. **A typical LED has a fixed voltage drop**, let's say 2.8V, and any voltage in excess is supplied into the series resistor (e.g. 5V-2.8V).

Assuming this is the case in your circuit, if the LED draws a fixed 2.8V, then the resistor will draw 2.2V. Then the series current will be

**Current = V/R = (5V-2.8V)/2.2k = 1mA**.

When you move to a 3.3V Arduino board, you want this current across the resistor to be the same. So, assuming the LED draws the same fixed 2.8V, then the resistor should be

**Resistance_new = V/I = (3.3V-2.8V)/1mA = 500 Ohms**

So by using a different voltage source, you just need to adjust the resistance to effectively supply the same current into the LED.

Comment: A real life power supply has a tolerance, as do LEDs and resistors. Other answers include [ronsimpson's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/665876/274544).

Comment: @greybeard ah yes, of course, but for a beginner in electronics, those "tolerances" are usually negligible (tenths or thousandths range) when you're dealing with simple dc circuits that do not require very precise calculations.

Comment: thanks @micropyre, I should have been more specific in my original description. My circuit diagram is just a smaller part of that PCB and the rest of the board requires 5v to operate correctly. I have edited my post for context.

Comment: @Warren oh in that case, you may discard my response then. I presumed it was a very simple circuit and just guessed the context.

In that case, you may need to implement a DC-DC boost converter / charge pump.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple circuit to drive the LEDs on 3.3 V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuZPYn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Drive Voltage]

[image: LED Currents]

Comment: If OP had the luxury of designing his own LED board then the answer posted 5 hours ago would be much simpler than this. However, OP has a board with 2.2k resistors in series so I don't see how this circuit would work on that.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that this was an existing board. My circuit could be modified by tying the emitters together and using that to drive the OP's board. However, the emitter followers lose about 0.7 V so there will be just 2.6 V for the LED and the limiting resistors. If the LED forward voltage is 1.5 V, the 2.2k resistors will limit current to just 500 uA.